# Loading hdf5 file Error

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network

Here is my my code

```
import theano
import numpy
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
model2 = Sequential()

model2.load_weights("/home/console/Desktop/Apu_code/_epoch_0_e199-0.04.hdf5")
'''model = loaded_models('.)'''

print('loaded')
```

and getting error :

```
Using Theano backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 7, in <module>
    model2.load_weights("/home/console/Desktop/Apu_code/_epoch_0_e199-0.04.hdf5")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2369, in load_weights
    str(len(flattened_layers)) + ' layers.')
Exception: You are trying to load a weight file containing 12 layers into a model with 0 layers.
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you are loading weights into a model that has no layers. You must create the same model to load those weights.

Comment: is there any easy way to load hdf5 file ?

Answer (score 0):

I just do

```
model0 = keras.models.load_model(hdf5Fname)
```

to load the file into the variable model0 in order to do sth like

```
prediction0 = model0.predict( image)[0][0]
```

and so on...